# Getting started with web sockets

Tags: html, websocket

I'm very interested in learning about the new feature in HTML5 called web sockets. I've looked into it and have come out with a few questions.

It seems that before I can start implementing this new technology into a web application of mine I need to have a web server which supports it. Does this involve downloading something and installing it on the said server? Is there more than one available? If so where do I find these?

I already have experience with JavaScript and HTML/CSS of course, Are there any other languages I will need to learn to start using web sockets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like this:

**[Edit this link is outdate]**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252829/what-browsers-support-html-5-websocket

http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-websockets-20091029

http://www.websockets.org/about.html