# How to implement a websocket-based service like stackoverflow in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, web-services, node.js, websocket

I'am building a chat application in node.js. Now I'am receiving new messages with ajax. I am sending request every 3 seconds. I noticed that stackoverflow doesn't send any requests to fetch new data. SO opens one stream ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/ (status 101) and in this way retrieves new content (like reputation, new comments, new posts). How to do this ?

Comment: i see socket.io demo in your future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ws://` protocol stands for websockets. You can read more about it in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). You can find in this question some pointers on how to [get started with websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988133/getting-started-with-web-sockets), while this question lists all the browsers that [support them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/what-browsers-support-html5-websocket-api).

Finally, the following question is a community wiki of all available libraries for nodejs:
[Which websocket library to use with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392260/which-websocket-library-to-use-with-node-js)

As Dandavis (brilliantly) pointed out, socket.io is quite a popular library, though I haven't personally tried it. It does however have much wider support (as shown by the large number of questions on [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket.io?sort=newest))